# gzip string, then base64 value of gzip

Tags: python, bash, base64, gzip, python-2.6

I want implement this line of `bash` in `python 2.6`.

`echo 'some string' | gzip | base64`

Right now I have this:

```
import io
import gzip
import base64

st = 'some string'
in = io.BytesIO(st)
gzz = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=in)
```

I'm not sure what to do next because I've been playing around with different methods and I keep getting errors for all the different methods I try. I'm not sure if I am headed in the right direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First `in` is a keyword, cannot be used as a variable name.

Then, create the `BytesIO` object empty, then use the `GZipFile` handle to write into it, using binary mode.

When done, retrieve the contents of the `BytesIO` stream and encode it with `base64.encode`

```
import io
import gzip
import base64

st = b'some string'
fo = io.BytesIO()
gzz = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=fo,mode="wb")

gzz.write(st)

print(base64.encodebytes(fo.getvalue()))
```

result:

```
b'H4sIAF8LSlkC/w==\n'
```

tested with Python 3.4, should work OK with python 2.x as well.